# bit wise manipulation on a 32-bit integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to read a 32 register,modify its first 8 bits[BIT7:BIT0] and write back its value.
Does the code below achieve that?

```
reg_val = register_read(register_object);
reg_val = ((reg_val & 0xffffff00) | new_value));
register_write(register_object,reg_val);
```

Also is it the most efficient way to achieve that.any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Comment: Too many right parentheses, but the obvious intent is correct (with the stipulation identified by EboMike that `new_value < 256` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless `new_value` is guaranteed only 8 bits wide you should ensure it:

```
reg_val = ((reg_val & 0xffffff00) | (new_value & 0xff));
```

> Also is it the most efficient way to achieve that?

Any compiler worth its salt will translate that into The Right Thing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `new_value` is guaranteed to be <256, and assuming that these are unsigned integers, then yes, this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: snap. And ensuring *unsigned* was something I forgot - good point.